# Gradle vs Compiler

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

From what I understand, Gradle is the package Builder for Android Studio. It tidies up resources, source code, and configuration files associated with the projects at the time of build, but does it then compile the code as well? Or does it convert the resources and dependencies to some form of compilable code and then sends it off to the compiler? From all the reading I have been doing, it is another layer to the application process.

This is how I envision the process currently:
Source code + resources + dependencies -> "linker"(Gradle) -> compiler -> compiled code -> Assembler -> Assembly Code

Comment: ' a grosso modo '  gradle is the build system, packages & processes all application resources, jar libraries, compiles your source code using the **Java SDK compiler** into Java Classes, then translates all classes to the DEX format (read about Dalvik) and finally packages (zip's) all the stuff into an APK file that is then uploaded to the phone. No Assembly code is involved for typical applications: They are executed by the Dalvik / ART virtual machine

Comment: So it is also bundled with the java compiler to produce APK's for android devices? note: the flow diagram was just to illustrate where i thought gradle resided in the process. i understand it is not involved in any assembly/assembler processes.

Comment: they are bundled separately. Gradle is a generic build software. What bundles it all together is Android Studio: It is a IDE environment  (IntelliJ Idea)  + java compiler (Oracle / others) + gradle builder + millions other tools such as JSLINT, Debugger, etc... Android studio uses Gradle internally to build Android applications.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Gradle the Equivalent of a Compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57844392/is-gradle-the-equivalent-of-a-compiler)