# Is Gradle the Equivalent of a Compiler?

Tags: android-gradle-plugin

From what I know, Gradle is a build automation system that combines and describes the app's project structure, configuration and dependencies to output an APK. Does this mean that the Gradle is equivalent to a compiler?

If they aren't equivalents, then what are the differences and how do they relate?

Comment: No. Gradle *uses* compiler. I mean, if you run a compilation and packing into a package by hand, you wouldn't call yourself a compiler, would you?

Comment: Generally a "compiler" is something that takes *(programming language) source code* and emits some form of *machine (or virtual machine) instructions*. So: no. Gradle might *use* a compiler; however, it is it self not a compiler.

Comment: Awesome. Short and sweet comments. If you clearly post the differences between a compiler and Gradle, then I'll green tick it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Gradle` is not equivalent to the compiler. Compilers primarily meant for translating the high-level language(i.e. `java`) into machine code or other intermediate code representation like `bytecode`. wheres `Gradle` is a build system that packages the code for you and makes it ready for compilation. If you take an example from android, under the hood, Gradle downloads the defined dependencies and packages everything for you without messing up and simplifies the development flow. It does all the dependencies management for the project. `Gradle` output is not the translated code, instead, you can say it's arranged code. finally `Gradle` is not equivalent of any `compiler`.
There is a similar question on [StackOverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36972761/gradle-vs-compiler). Rather putting post multiple times, you can accept satisfactorily answer, so moderators can remove the duplicate/unaccepted one.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that post but it didn't have a clear answer.